Rollup, babel - Using fs node built-in in a react app with rollup
I love rollup, but this thing has been a show-stopper.
I am not able to access and use fs methods with a simple react app. I can log fs object at rollup level, but it breaks run-time accessing fs.
I am facing two errors, when i mock fs in rollup, fs is not null runtime, but it is a mock empty object, useless itself.
If I do not mock it, i get 'fs' could not be find, use '.', './' or '../'
Can someone see what I am missing here, I have tried everything suggested online, resolve node modules, external, builtin, globals, polyfill plugins.
Is this a babel thing?
Here is my rollup.comfig.mjs
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import externals from "rollup-plugin-node-externals";

export default {
    input: './index.js',
    output: [ 
        {
            format: 'umd',
            file: 'dist/index.js',
            sourcemap: true,
            name: 'test',
        },
        {
        file: 'dist/index.cjs.js',
        format: 'cjs',
        name: 'test',
        sourcemap: 'inline',
    }
  ],
    plugins: [
        replace({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        }),
        externals(),
        nodeResolve({
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
            browser: true,
            preferBuiltins: true,
            moduleDirectories: ['src', 'node_modules']
         }),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            requireReturnsDefault: 'auto',
            exclude: 'path',
            ignore: ['fs', 'path', 'utils'],
        }),
        babel({
            babelHelpers: 'bundled',
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        }),
        serve({
            open: true,
            contentBase: ['dist'],
            port: 3000
          }),
        livereload('dist'),
     ],
};

Tried, loading node built-in fs methods with various suggested rollup plugins, node-resolve, external, polyfill
I am expecting to be able to simply access fs library.
